# How do you clear the cache in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Everywhere I look I see instructions saying to go Chrome > Tools > Clear browsing data. There's no "Tools" option in that menu. I've hunted high and low through the preferences and developer tools but cannot find anything that lets me clear the cache.

My Mac Chrome version is 39.0.2171.71 which apparently is up to date.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) on Mac OSX. It's under `More tools`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea there was an entire menu stashed away in there. In fact I'd never even noticed those three lines until now.